# Does the compile function require any special configuration in Django?

Tags: python, django, compilation, exec

I have a piece of code written out as a string that I would like to execute in a view in Django. It works in the python shell interpreter, but not in Django. I am using python 3.6 and Django 2.1. Here is an example of the code:

```
a = 'def solution():\n\timport random\n\treturn random.randint(1,10)'
exec(compile(a, '', 'exec'))
print(solution())
```

The above code in the interpreter will run as expected and print a random number between 1 and 10. In Django I get an error

```
NameError: name 'solution' is not defined
```

Thank you for any help

Comment: In which file of django do you try to run this code?

Comment: updated question to include that i'm trying this in a view

Answer (score 0):

why don't you simply do the following

```
from random import randint
print(randint(1, 10))
```

Besides, where are you executing the code?
I can run it within my `settings.py`

Comment: I could, but the objective is to run the code from a string and return a value.

Comment: I can run it in my settings.py. However, pylint complains, that it does not know solution() - for obvious reason

Comment: hmm that's interesting. i'm trying to run it in a view

Comment: Ya, there it fails for me too.

Comment: Could you elaborate why you have this objective?

Comment: this string is stored in a database, so this was the only way i could think of to run it.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to only store the interval as tuple and than insert it in the formula?

Comment: it would be - in this specific case - but the return may not always be a randomint like that